# Bootstrap v3.3.6 drop down submenu items does not expand in mobile

Tags: angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have created a web site using angular 1 ,bootstrap,CSS3. I have used bootstrap navbar and it works fine in desktop mode.However , submenu does not work in mobile version.The main menu item expands properly.However I have three submenus present and I am unable to see the sub menu drop down items at all.I am badly fighting with this for 3 weeks now unable to fix it. It is basically a single page application with angular routing logic

Bootstrap version : 3.3.6

My website is [www.europeansaga.com](http://europeansaga.com) where you can find this issue in mobile mode.

Code is below along with HTML and JS model containing the menu data

```css
JS code inside my controller

$scope.mainMenu = [ {

      name : 'Home',
      hasChild : false,
      iconClass : 'glyphicon glyphicon-home',
      url : '/'
     }, {

      name : 'Gallery',
      hasChild : false,
      iconClass : 'glyphicon glyphicon-camera',
      isActive : false,
      url : '/gallery'
     }, {
      
      name : 'Destination',
      hasChild : true,
      iconClass : 'glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker',
      isActive : false,
      url : '/destinations'
     }, {

      name : 'Best of Solo Travel',
      hasChild : true,
      iconClass : 'glyphicon glyphicon-heart',
      isActive : false,
      url : '/bestOfSoloTravel'
     }, {

      name : 'Travel Planning',
      hasChild : true,
      iconClass : 'glyphicon glyphicon-book',
      isActive : false,
      url : '/travelPlanning'
     } ];
     var destinationSubMenuItems = [  {
      name : 'Iceland',
      url : 'Iceland'
     }, {
      name : 'Amsterdam',
      url : 'Amsterdam'
     }, {
      name : 'Barcealona',
      url : 'Barcealona'
     }, {
      name : 'Santorini',
      url : 'Santorini'
     }, {
      name : 'La Tomatina 2016',
      url : 'La-Tomatina-2016'
     }, {
      name : 'Croatia',
      url : 'Croatia'
     }, {
      name : 'Italy',
      url : 'Italy'
     } ];
     var travelPlanningSubMenuItems = [ {
      name : 'Barcealona',
      url : 'BarcealonaPlanning'
     }, {
      name : 'Santorini',
      url : 'SantoriniPlanning'
     },{
      name : 'Salzgermmut',
      url : 'SalzgermmutPlanning'
     },
     {
      name : 'La-Tomatina',
      url : 'La-Tomatina-Bunol-Planning-Information'
     }];
     var bestofSoloTravelSubMenuItems = [ {
      name : 'Nomads acquaintance',
      url : 'Solo-Travel-Acquaintances'
     }, {
      name : 'Hostel Culture',
      url : 'Hostel-Culture-Experience-In-Europe'
     }, {
      name : 'Unleashing cooking skills',
      url : 'How-to-prepare-Indian-Food-in-SoloTravel'
     } ];
     $scope.selectedDestination = null;
     $scope.submenu = {};
     $scope.submenu['Travel Planning'] = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < travelPlanningSubMenuItems.length; i++) {
      $scope.submenu['Travel Planning'].push(travelPlanningSubMenuItems[i]);
     }
     $scope.submenu['Destination'] = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < destinationSubMenuItems.length; i++) {
      $scope.submenu['Destination'].push(destinationSubMenuItems[i]);
     }
     $scope.submenu['Best of Solo Travel'] = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < bestofSoloTravelSubMenuItems.length; i++) {
      $scope.submenu['Best of Solo Travel'].push(bestofSoloTravelSubMenuItems[i]);
     }
```

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="site-navigation-inner col-sm-12">
      <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="btn navbar-toggle"
        data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
         class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
         class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
       <div id="logo">
        <h1 class="site-name">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/" rel="home">EUROPEAN SAGA
          - A SOLO ADVENTURE</a>
        </h1>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li
         ng-class="{dropdown: menuItem.hasChild,active: menuItem.isActive}"
         ng-repeat="menuItem in mainMenu"><a
         class="dropdown-toggle centerAlignItems" data-toggle="dropdown"
         href="#{{menuItem.url}}"> <span
          class="{{menuItem.iconClass}}"></span> {{menuItem.name}}<span
          ng-if="menuItem.hasChild" class="caret"></span>
        </a>
         <ul ng-class="{'dropdown-menu': menuItem.hasChild}"
          ng-if="menuItem.hasChild">
          <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in submenu[menuItem.name]"><a
           href="#{{value.url}}">{{value.name}}</a></li>
         </ul></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
```

As per Mikkel's suggestion placed the below code inside document.ready to server as CSS class onclick. It still does not work. Please can someone help. I am unable to expose my website since this is one of the major issues that I am facing

```js
    // Patch for bootstrap hamburger menu
     $(".navbar-responsive-collapse").click(function (e) {
         if ($(e.target).is('a')) {
             $(this).collapse('hide');
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a fix which I use in my projects for this. Sorry you had to waste your time chasing it.

```
// Patch for bootstrap hamburger menu
$(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse.in', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('a')) {
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry this didnt work I place the below code inside document ready block but nothing work. The issue still remains the same where sub menu does not expand at all. I have 3 submenus (if you look at the web site you will understand).

Comment: Mikkel I have updated the question now with correct issue. Please visit the site and you will be able to see the actual issue. I am unable to properly expand and see submenu drop down items (Destinations,best of solo travel,Travel planning - they have sub menu items) which are not getting expanded in the mobile